# java.util.Stack and Fragments on Android

Tags: java, android

I saw a code using Stack that pushes a Fragment, do you think using Stack is necessary since for me i think Fragments already have that right?

Comment: IIRC FragmentManager already manages fragments in a stack-like manner.

Comment: that's what i thought, i think the code i'm reading right now is weird hehehe. thanks